# How does the SNTP app of the lwip component in esp32 set the time it receives?

Tags: c, esp32

The [SNTP app in the lwip component](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/lwip/apps/sntp/sntp.c) of the espressif esp32 library sets the time of the system such that calling

```
sntp_setoperatingmode(SNTP_OPMODE_POLL); 
sntp_setservername(0, "pool.ntp.org");
sntp_init();
wait_until_time_updated();
sntp_stop();
time(&now);
```

sets the current time into `now`.

The `time()` function is defined [here](https://github.com/espressif/newlib-esp32/blob/master/newlib/libc/time/time.c) and uses `_gettimeofday_r()` to retreive it.

`sntp_init()` utilizes `sntp_process()`, after receiving a response, to evaluate the response and set the time. From what I understand, it uses the function(?) `SNTP_SET_SYSTEM_TIME()` to set the time; however, I can not find where this function(?) is defined - and thus cant find how the `sntp` app sets the time that is retrieved by `time()`.

How does `sntp_init`, of the sntp app in the lwip component for esp32, set the time that is retrieved by `time()`